# How do I check if the value attribute is equal object key, if its equal take the key value and add a class to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, object

Evening guys, I have a a dropdown based on change of that drop down in need get the value and check if its equal to object key if its true take the object key value and addclass to it. Here is the sample js code.

```js
    var attrValue = "london";
    var myObject = {"london ":
    {"show ":"#london1 #london2 "}, 
    "russia ": 
   {"show ":"#moscow1, #moscow2"}};
    
    function mytest(myObject, key) {
     for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
      var keys = myObject.key[i];
      if (attrValue == keys) {
       //get London keys and use value to add show or hide class 
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: @Taplar I am declaring the object so that I access the keys and get the value is the key matches attrValue

Comment: @Taplar My apologies I removed the double quotes

Comment: @Taplar yes thats the code I trying to play around with

Comment: You need to fix your syntax errors still

Comment: Which new line? @Taplar

Comment: Every single string (`""`) that has a new line in it is going to complain.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m7padu0t/1/ would be an example of an object declaration without the invalid new lines.

Comment: @Taplar I have edited the breaking lines

Comment: @Taplar any assist will be of help and an advise will be appreciated

Comment: You can't use array iteration on an ordinary object: `myObject` is not an array and `myObject.length` is undefined.

Comment: @traktor53 any help on the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm in posted code appears too complicated if the task is to  access the `myObject` property whose name is taken from a select element's selected option value.

Problems with `myObject` definitions are addressed in the example:

- Quotes can be placed around property names when defining JavaScript objects, *but the practice is often just following JSON syntax requirements for text strings*  - code only requires quotes around property names that don't meet the syntax for identifiers.
- If quotes are placed around property name definitions anyway, *avoid trailing spaces in the property name string* - they become part of the property name and cause a lot of confusion when trying to debug code. (The post contains trailing spaces in "london ", "russia " and "show ")

Here is an example that only looks at own properties of `myObject`:

```js
"use strict";

var myObject = {
    london: { show: "#london1 #london2"}, 
    russia: { show: "#moscow1, #moscow2"}
};

document.getElementById("dropdown")
  .addEventListener("change",
    function() {
      var key, selector, option;
      option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
      key = option.value;
      if(  myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        selector = myObject[key].show;
        console.log( "do something with " + selector);
      }
      else {
        console.log("No key found for " + option.text);
      }
    }, false);
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="london">London</option>
   <option value="russia">Russia</option>
   <option value="problem">Problem</option>
</select>
```